# Why are phonewords called vanity numbers?

Tags: word-usage

> A [vanity number](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanity_number) is a local or toll-free telephone number for which a subscriber requests an easily remembered sequence of numbers for marketing purposes.
>
> While many of these are [phonewords](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoneword) (such as 1-800-Flowers, 313-DETROIT, 1-800-Taxicab or 1-800-Battery), occasionally all-numeric vanity phone numbers are used.

Accorging to [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=phoneword%2Cphone%20word%2Cvanity%20numbers&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cvanity%20numbers%3B%2Cc0) the expression  is from the late ’80s but why ‘vanity’?

Is vanity number the more common expression to refer to these  often  used numeric/alphanumeric numbers?

Is it only  AmE usage or  is it used also in British or other English dialects?

Comment: _Vanity numbers:_ by analogy with [_vanity plates_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanity_plate). American usage, I'd think. Phone numbers aren't generally alphabetised that way in the UK. _Vanity number_ is a new one to me.

Comment: @tmgr I don't think anywhere still alphabetises like that in the mobile era. But I definitely did see phone numbers like this in the UK in the 80s/90s.

Comment: @Jonita It's a dying art, indeed! I've seen 'em too, back in the day, but they were nowhere near as ubiquitous as in the States; we just didn't have the letters on our rented BT rotary phones. But all that's neither here nor there re OP's question; I don't think they were ever called _vanity numbers_ in the UK, be they nice number combinations or phonewords. Still, _vanity plate_ is now generally understood in the UK (as opposed to _personalised number plate,_ which just rolls off the tongue), so I'd think most folk would 'get it' even if they'd never heard it.

Comment: Because it's advertising. Which is vain. Like @tmgr said, like vanity license plates.

Comment: Vanity phone numbers do exist in the UK, and have been around for decades, but the UK ones are based on *numbers,* not letters. For example the AA (automobile association) breakdown assistance number is 0800 88 77 66 - the 0800 is the UK "free call" prefix, and the rest is easy to remember. British Telecom's general enquiries number is 0800 800 150. Where I live, there are two taxi firms with numbers 626262 and 757575 (with the local area code prefix, of course). In a  sense you could call numbers like 999 (emergency services) and 111 (health service 24-hour telephone support) vanity numbers.

Comment: … Phone directory enquiries use them as well. 118 is the general prefix for directory enquiry services in the UK and two companies have the numbers 118 118, and 118 24 7 (open all hours!)

Comment: @alephzero - thanks, but are these numbers called “vanity numbers” in the UK?

Comment: @alephzero What you say is true, of course. I didn't mean to imply otherwise. I don't think anyone actually calls them _vanity numbers_ in the UK, though.

Comment: In British English the phrase "personalised" or "personal" has been used as a more neutral description of things like these, as @tmgr mentions. "Vanity" has a slightly negative connotation as an unwelcome personality trait, as other answers and comments mention; but that doesn't appear to be the case in US English, and this usage is becoming more accepted in British English usage as well.

Comment: @Jim In the US, vanity plates/numbers aren't an official term either. Nearly all state DMVs call them personalized license plates and you see "custom phone number".

Comment: Another example is "Vanity domain", which are personal domains, e.g. for web homepage or email.

Comment: Flagged for unclear question. If you are unsure of the meaning of the word "vanity", you should look up a dictionary, as single-word requests are also banned here.

Comment: @aaa90210 - I  know what vanity means, but  the question is, if you care to read, why local and toll-free numbers are called “vanity numbers” in the USA. Btw single word requests are not banned on ELU.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The [AHD](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=vanity&submit.x=84&submit.y=18)'s primary meaning of the noun *vanity* is typical:

> Excessive pride in one's appearance or accomplishments; conceit.

It follows that a *vanity* product or service is one that is purchased in order to feed one's vanity, by drawing attention or by artificially boosting one's stature to outward appearances. The oldest derived term in the OED is *vanity publisher*, attested from at least 1922, *a publisher who publishes only at the author's expense*. In other words, a vanity publisher is a press that someone pays so that he or she can call him- or herself a published author, in contrast to a traditional publisher, which would pay the author for printing rights, as well as in contrast to self-publishing, where the author produces and maintains control of the entire product.

A more familiar term is *vanity plate*, for a car license plate on which the registrant chooses a custom/personal word or slogan instead of having random letters or numbers assigned.

[image: Vanity license plate reading JEDIIAM from Wikimedia Commons]

Vanity phone numbers, vanity URLs, vanity DNS nameservers… these are all very mildly disparaging terms for ways where someone can pay a little extra money to stand out from the crowd.

Comment: It doesn't strike me as disparaging, per se, but I agree with the rest of your answer.

Comment: It doesn't have to be about paying money. A custom Bitcoin address generated by expending computing power is called a vanity address, for example.

Answer (score 9):

Usually things are given the "Vanity" prefix when you're paying extra to get something that doesn't serve a functional purpose.

As @tmgr noted, the most common analogy is Vanity Plates, a car license plate that spells a word, but doesn't add anything, [Like this one for £4000](https://www.plates4less.co.uk/personalised-number-plate/BO07NDS). Vanity publishing, is where an author pays for something to be published instead of the publisher paying the author, which is the more traditional situation.

The underlying premise is that the person buying this vanity service wants it for nothing more than to show off. It is potentially slightly misplaced with respect to these phone numbers, as they serve the purpose of making the businesses' number more memorable than a rival service. Very useful in the pre-mobile era.

From Google dictionary

> **vanity**  1. excessive pride in or admiration of one's own appearance or achievements.
>   "it flattered his vanity to think I was in love with him"
>   synonyms:   conceit, conceitedness, self-conceit, narcissism, self-love, self-admiration, self-regard, self-absorption, self-obsession, self-centredness, egotism, egoism, egocentrism, egomania;

Comment: I'm not sure why vanity phone numbers would be less useful in the "mobile era". Sure, these days you can save numbers on your phone and attach a name to them, so you don't have to remember your friend's phone numbers. But with a business name, the idea is that you see or hear it in an advertisement and remember it later. Like, I don't have 1-800-FLOWERS on my cell phone. But if I had a sudden desire to order flowers, I remember that number even though I've never called them in my life.

Comment: @Jay, while that's true, in the mobile era I don't have to remember any numbers any more because the last flower shop I used is already in my phone. A decent website is more useful than a memorable number, so maybe I should have said "smart phone" rather than "mobile" era.

Comment: It's definitely less useful these days when you can instantly click on a phone number in an ad/webpage, or google anyone's number. I'm not sure I'd ever think "I need flowers! I'll call 1-800-FLOWERS!" without being sure what business is on the other end and whether they were any good, but different people are different.